# How to properly use cmake to build a cross-platform c++ project that includes pre-compiled third-party libraries

Tags: c++, .net, dll, cmake, dllexport

A bit of background: I'm attempting to build a cross-platform C++ project using CMAKE, that I will be able to call from within a dotnet project. I have a large, existing dotnet library that I've created that I want to be able to use to manage/manipulate data. I have also received from a third-party, a pre-compiled C++ library that I need to use to ingest the data. I have received the precompiled, third-party code as .dll and .lib (for Windows) and .a and .so (for Linux). I have also received all of the header files for the third-party library. My plan is to create a wrapper project, around the third-party C++ code, that exports C-style functions that I can consume using standard dotnet interop code. To this end, I have created a new project, let's call it "ThirdPartyWrapper". This project has the following file structure:

```
ThirdPartyWrapper
   | - include
      | - ThirdPartyHeader1.h
      | - ThirdPartyHeader2.h
      | - ...
   | - lib
      | - ThirdPartyAPI.dll
      | - ThirdPartyAPI.lib
      | - libThirdPartyAPI.a
      | - libThirdPartyAPI.so
   | - CMakeLists.txt
   | - CMakeSettings.json
   | - ThirdPartyWrapper.cpp
   | - ThirdPartyWrapper.h
```

Where "include" contains all the header files for the third-party library and "lib" includes all the precompiled binaries for both Windows and Linux.

In order to be able to interact with the C++ library via dotnet, I am exporting C-style functions that encapsulate the specific methods that I need. The ThirdPartyWrapper.h file looks like this:

```
#ifndef EXPORT
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

EXPORT void initialize();
EXPORT void doSomething();
EXPORT void doSomethingElse();
```

My CMakeLists.txt file is short and looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.21)

project ("ThirdPartyWrapper")

//declare this as a "module" since we don't have any associated "imports"
add_library (tpw MODULE "ThirdPartyWrapper.cpp" "ThirdPartyWrapper.h")

//include all of the third-party header files in projects "include" directory
target_include_directories(tpw PRIVATE "include")

//use the find_library command to locate the appropriate library for current platform
//all the libraries are in the project's "lib" directory 
find_library(lib NAMES "ThirdPartyAPI" PATHS "lib" REQUIRED true)

//link the found third-party library to the project 
target_link_libraries(tpw lib)
```

This seems simple and straightforward. But it doesn't work. I have only attempted to build the project on Windows (I'll cross the Linux bridge after I get it to build and run on Windows). CMake generation appears to succeed (using Ninja). But when I attempt to build the project, I encounter the following error:

> LNK1104 cannot open file lib.lib

From my research, it sounds like the linker is expecting a .lib file, containing functions marked with __declspec(dllimport). But the project doesn't need any imports and the use of the MODULE type in the add_library command should ensure that only the dll is created.

I suspect that the issue is with how the third-party libraries are being found and selected? Should I use another method to select the platform-dependent, third-party library to use?

Or, is the problem rooted in the fact that I include the third-party header files but not the third-party source code?

Or, is it something else? I'm VERY new to CMAKE so I would appreciate any help and guidance that this community is willing to provide, whether that has to do with how to structure my projects, which cmake commands to use, or which technologies to use, or even higher-level concepts and ideas.

One last thing: I'm aware that I might be able to use CMAKE to build the project as a C++/CLR project. If this is the way to go, I'd appreciate some instruction on how to make this happen. As it is, I plan to explore this option after I get the exist projecting building and working as a simple dll.

Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Comment: Why did you specify `lib` here: `target_link_libraries(tpw lib)`? What is `lib`?? Is there any library `liblib.lib` supposed to be created with your cmake setup?

Comment: Try `${lib}` .. currently you're not using the CMake variable you set using find library but rather the text *lib*. Therefore CMake tries to link against *lib*.lib